# I want to make a website like Stack Overflow but is as fast as Discord, which languages and frameworks should I use?

Tags: web-apps, web-development

I want to make a website like Stack Overflow but is as fast as Discord, which languages and frameworks should I use? I like stack overflow, but hate the question limit and the like/dislike system. If I would want to make a website like Stack Overflow but as fast as Discord, what languages and frameworks do you recommend? When I say 'website like Stack Overflow', I simply mean the question and answer system. I might add features later though. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Stack Overflow is way, way faster for me than slow Discord. If you want to get fast, do it in C. Nearly no one uses C for websites and it shows. All websites are bloated and slow. It is possible to create websites that load pages instantaneously. Even without resorting to C. You just need a different mindset and have most stuff be static.